# Two background patterns for a wrapper div

Tags: html, css

I wanted to know is it possible to have two background patterns for a wrapper div. 
For example -

```
<div id="wrapper">
Hello
</div>

#wrapper {
  background:url(../images/pattren.png) repeat-x; 
}
```

Is it possible to have this `pattern.png` repeat only till 50% of the div and have another pattren like `pattren_flipped.png` for another 50%? Is it possible to do it without having another two divs inside?

Comment: CSS3 allows multiple background-images, but I doubt you can have more than one that repeats.

Comment: You can have multiple backgrounds, but you can't prevent image from filling all 100% width or height if it's repeated.

Comment: This article may help http://css-tricks.com/stacking-order-of-multiple-backgrounds/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't force pattern to fill just 50% width or height if it's repeated. But maybe you can emulate this behaviour using `before` and `after` pseudo selectors:

```
#wrapper:before, #wrapper:after {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    content: '';
    z-index: -1;
}
#wrapper:before {
    left: 0;
    background: url(pattern1.png) repeat-x 0 0;
}
#wrapper:after {
    right: 0;
    background: url(pattern2.png) repeat-x 0 0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dfsq/PwSD4/

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this:

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="inner">
        Hello
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#wrapper { height: 800px; position: relative; width: 500px; z-index: 2; }
.inner { position: relative; z-index: 2; }

#wrapper:before {
    background:url("http://css-tricks.com/images/Treehouse_600x500_02.jpg") repeat-x;
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 50%;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}
#wrapper:after{
    background:url("http://css-tricks.com/images/ads/wufoo-600x600-red.png") repeat-x;
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 50%;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/79rAA/)

Ideally the inner div wouldn't be necessary, it may not be but I couldn't get the text inside the wrapper above the background images without it

EDIT: The inner div isn't necessary at all, look at dfsq's answer (can't believe I didn't think of that!)

Unfortunatley this will only work in [IE8+](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-gencontent) so you might have a bit of a problem if you need compatability with older versions of IE, other than the above I don't think there's another (mostly) cross browser way to do this